# Wordpress & Woocommerce: add to cart button on variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have been researching this for awhile now and I cant seem to find an answer or feasible solution.  I know I have a conflict with my scripts which is preventing my add to cart button to show after selecting variations on woocommerce.  I have tried deactivating all plugins and it was no help, I switched themes to the default twenty twelve theme and of course it works then so I know it is a theme issue.  I am running a child theme of WP Foundation but even after going through the theme and commenting out the enqueued scripts and everything it still is not working.

Im not sure how to troubleshoot this down to which specific script is causing the issue.  Looking in the theme I have both wp_head and wp_footer where they belong.  Can someone help me narrow down the problem script or a possible solution?

I really appreciate it

Development link is: http://surfquest.itestwebpageshere2.biz/product/woodcut/

Answer (score -2):

Fixed the issue by intalling an earlier version of woocommerce and everything works fine.

I am now running Woocommerce 1.6.6 and Wordpress 3.5.1

Cheers